# VBA Array Type Mismatch in if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have no clue how this is happening; I swear everything looks correct yet I am getting an error. It should be very simple. Here is the code:

```
Dim ExceptionArray() As String
    
    ReDim ExceptionArray(3)
    
    ExceptionArray(0) = "Action Required"
    ExceptionArray(1) = "No Funds"
    ExceptionArray(2) = "This account will be verified"
    RowCountTotal = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To RowCountTotal
    
        For j = 0 To 2
            If ExceptionArray(j) = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value Then 'type mismatch error here
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: i checked and its a string..

Comment: It couldn't be that missing `"` at the end of the "No Funds" line, could it?

Comment: I tested your code sure with  ExceptionArray(1) = "No Funds" it worked, no type mismatch error occurred.

Comment: Can you post some sample data, or at least a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

`Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value` is a `Variant` that you are comparing to a `String` value.

In most cases, the variant subtype is `Variant/Double` or `Variant/String` (or a `Variant/Date`), and it "just works" because VBA is performing implicit type conversions here, and pretty much any type can be safely converted to a string for comparison purposes.

Except if we're looking at a `Variant/Error`.

If `Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value` is a `Variant/Error` (look for `#N/A`, `#VALUE!`, `#REF!`, etc. worksheet cell error at row `i`, column D), you get a *type mismatch* because `Variant/Error` does not implicitly (or explicitly, for that matter) convert to or from a `String`.

You need to validate the `Variant` subtype of the cell value you're looking at:

```vb
Dim CellValue As Variant
CellValue = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value

If Not IsError(CellValue) Then
    If ExceptionArray(j) = CellValue Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
End Of
```

...and then [use Union ranges to delete rows much faster with a single worksheet write operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013656/1188513) instead of manipulating a `For...Next` loop counter in the body of that loop, or instead of iterating backwards to account for row indexes offsetting as you delete them.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Rows

```vb
Option Explicit
 
Sub deleteRows()

    Const ExceptionsList As String _
        = "Action Required,No Funds,This account will be verified"
    
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    Dim RowCountTotal As Long
    RowCountTotal = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To RowCountTotal
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value, _
                Exceptions, 0)) Then
            If drg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = Sheet1.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set drg = Union(drg, Sheet1.Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not drg Is Nothing Then
        drg.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This proposed solution uses the [AutoFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) and [SpecialCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) `Range` methods to show only the `Rows` to be deleted and delete all of them at once.

```
Sub Delete_Exceptions()
Dim aException As Variant, lRow As Long
    
    aException = [{"Action Required","No Funds","This account will be verified"}]   'Set Array
    With Sheet1
    
        If Not (.AutoFilter Is Nothing) Then .AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter   'Clear AutoFilter if active
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        With .Range("A1:D1").Resize(lRow)
            
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, _
                Criteria1:=aException, Operator:=xlFilterValues             'Filter all exception rows
            .Offset(1).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count) _
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete           'Delete all exception rows
            .AutoFilter                                                     'Clear AutoFilter
    
    End With: End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. As a side note, in this case, it is more accurate to resize first to a smaller range and only then do the offset: `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)...`, which would prevent `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error` occurring in the highly unlikely event, when the range would go to the bottom-most row of the worksheet.